# How to hide an image when we hover it?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a list of images (of some items) and i am showing them in a grid fashion using ng-repeat.I want that when i hover on any image then image should be disappear and new div of same size as the image should open with all the sub components of that image item.My implementation is following,
when i hover on any image , instead of required behaviour some image flipping is happening. 
I am facing problems in achieving this goal.Is there any way to do this.

```
  **hovers.html**
    <html>
   <div   ng-repeat="a in modules">
   <md-card  class="image">   <img src="a.image_url" />
    <div class="overlay">
          /*Some items  */                 
        </div>          
        </md-card> </div>   </html>


   **style.css**


  .image {
  position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%; }

.overlay {
 display: none; }

  .image:hover {display:none;}

  .image:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
 top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .image:hover .overlay img {
    vertical-align: top;
    }

          **home.html**

  <div    class="columns"  width="100%" height="100%">
   <custom-hover    ng-repeat="a in modules" 
            module="a" layout="row">

    </custom-hover>

           </div>



          home.js

   "use strict";

 function customHover($compile){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
             module: "=",

             },

          templateUrl:  "hovers.html",                                                                                                     
    controller: function($scope, $mdDialog) {
        console.log("=======",$scope.module)


    }

         }
            }; 

         module.exports = customHover;
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and have your full HTML and your full CSS completely separate so that I can get a better sense of what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure CSS Image Hover Without Using Background Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153561/pure-css-image-hover-without-using-background-images)

Comment: Do i need to edit this again??

Comment: Your code is very unclear and I am unable to tell what you are doing or trying to do. Edit it to be clear and separate the code so we may help you.

Comment: Okk Sorry for my incorrect editing.I fix it.

Comment: md-card is something from angular, so maybe try using a div to contain it and see what happens.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. so i don't about editing much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to keep element space, change `display` to `visibility`

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  visiblity: visible;
  width: 100%;
 
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
}

.image:hover img{
  visibility: hidden;
}

.image:hover .overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.2);
 overflow: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" ng-repeat="a in modules">
  <md-card>
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/global-symbol_318-68107.jpg" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </md-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but in my case the image tag which i want to hide via hover has src attribute changing(means value of src is a variable not static reference).

Comment: I have tried your solution works fine , thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should put `hover` against your image container which you named class=`image`, but hide image-self, so it should be:

```
  .image:hover img{
    display: none;
  }

  .image:hover .overlay{
    display: block;
  }
```

Here is the html:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        .image {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .image:hover img{
          display: none;
        }

        .image:hover .overlay{
          display: block;
        }

        .myCard{
          width: 200px;
          height: 120px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        .overlay{
          display: none;
        }

      </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="com">
      <div  class="image" ng-repeat="a in modules">
        <md-card class="myCard">
          <img ng-src="{{a.image_url}}"/>
          <div class="overlay">
            {{a.desc}}
          </div>
        </md-card>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

angular js:

```
  angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("com", function($scope){
      $scope.modules = [
        {
          "image_url": "a.jpg",
          "desc": "cocktail"
        },
        {
          "image_url": "b.jpg",
          "desc": "cookie"
        },
        {
          "image_url": "c.jpg",
          "desc": "cake"
        }
      ];
    });
```

Default shows pictures, when you hover, it will hide picture and display `desc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man i think that solution might work,i am gonna test it. But can u please tell me the reason of the problem i am having as i am new and learning about AngularJS,CSS etc.

Comment: The problem is here: `image:hover {display:none;}`, class `image` is image container, it should either display image-self or words, so you shouldn't hide the container. It should hide image-self when hover,  `.image:hover img{
    display: none;
  }`

Comment: Ya , I got your point. But i am having the same flipping problem yet.Please help me because this issue become nightmare for me.Actually i have buid a custom directive and the html content that i want to show in my directive is the same as i have given in the html code.So basically i am using ng-repeat inside my custom directive tag.